# moviepy: How to define the ending part backwards for cut?

Tags: python, video, gif, moviepy

To this question I am referring to the example from http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/making-animated-gifs-from-video-files-with-python/

To be exactly, to these codes I refer.

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clip = (VideoFileClip("frozen_trailer.mp4")
        .subclip((1,22.65),(1,23.2))
        .resize(0.3))
clip.write_gif("use_your_head.gif")
```

The code above selects the part between 1’22.65 (1 minute 22.65 seconds) and 1’23.2.

**My question:** How to define the ending part **backwards**? How to define the `subclip`， so it cut e.g. the beginning 1’22.65, and cut the last 3 minute 20.15 seconds?

I have many MP4s with different length, but they have same beginning and ending parts. It will be very convenient.

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is getting the length of the video and subtracting a set length from this number with a datetime object. Is there a way to get a length of a movie in your specific library of choice?

Comment: @ateesdalejr Oh! That is a very good idea! Thanks for the hint! I have not thought about that. :-)

Comment: not Python, but I have a Bash example of using ffprobe and ffmpeg to do what, I think, you want - https://github.com/Offbeatmammal/VTrim ... same logic can apply to a python script